# Oracle Client on windows server log location?

Tags: oracle, logging, location

Rather simple question, for the Standard Oracle Client install (10GR2+)

Is there a log file that is kept on the Client side?

If so, where does it reside?

I can find a lot of notes on where to find them on the server itself, but not the Oracle Client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, the client does not log anything.

You can enable various sorts of logs on the client-- one of the various levels of SQL*Net trace would be the most common-- but these would generally only be enabled in order to track down the source of some particular bug.  They would not be left enabled during normal operation.